Increasing padding of child div doesn't increase total width of parent div
My application allows users to change padding of .telBlock input dynamically.
Requirement is to increase overall width of .telInsideBlock in case padding for the input was changed.
With the current CSS width of .telInsideBlock always stays the same on changing padding of the input.
However if adding padding for .telInsideBlock -> div grows.
I cannot change .telBlock nor .telBlockLabel, I also cannot add any new CSS classes.
How can I achieve this?


.telBlock {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 16px;
}

.telInsideBlock {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 0%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid rgb(225, 223, 221);
  border-radius: 2px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.telSpan {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  background-color: rgb(243, 242, 241);
  align-items: center;
  align-self: stretch;
  display: flex;
}

.telBlock span[hidden] {
  display: none;
}

.telBlockLabel {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  width: 100%;
}

.telBlock input {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(250, 249, 248);
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 14px;
  flex: 2 1 0%;
  border: none;
  z-index: -1;
}
<div class="telBlock">
  <label class="telBlockLabel" title="Tel" for="telId">Address 1: Phone</label>
  <div class="telInsideBlock">
    <span class="telSpan">+123</span><input title="Tel" placeholder="Tel" type="tel" id="telId">
  </div>
</div>



